# Don't return poshytip under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I want to show poshytips when I mouseover elements in a class, but only if they meet the conditions specified in the content function.  If not, I do not want an empty bubble to appear.

```
$('[class~="label"]').poshytip({
            slide: false, 
            followCursor: true, 
            alignTo: 'cursor', 
            showTimeout: 0, 
            hideTimeout: 0, 
            alignX: 'center', 
            alignY: 'inner-bottom', 
            className: 'tip-ihme',
            offsetY: 10,
            content: function() {
                if(this.id.length>25 & sbar.settings.stackBy == 'region') {
                    return this.id
                }   
            },
            liveEvents: true
        });
    }
```

However, a small (empty) bubble still shows when I mouseover the elements who do not meet this specification (ie, this.id.length<25).  Is there a way to filter out the selection in the jquery call?  I tried array style filtering:

```
  $('[class~="label"]').filter(function(d) { return d.id.length>25}).poshytip(....
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('[class~="label"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id').length>25)
    {
        $(this).poshytip({
           // your code
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to implement the conditions specified in the content function; ie, if something does not meet the specification, no bubble appears: I hope the edit above clarifies

Comment: I changed my answer according to your requirement.